# Putting statement on one line when using remove braces refactoring in ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, indentation

ReSharper has a feature that allows you to remove braces on single-line statements.

Unfortunately it puts the statement on its own line, but I want everything to be on the same line. Is there any way to achieve this through configuration?

I've been tinkering with the countless options that ReSharper provides for formatting and style but did not find a suitable option that fits my needs.

*Before refactoring:*

[image]

*After refactoring:*

[image]

Desired outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like ReSharper does not put embedded statements on the same line, I filed [RSRP-492431](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-492431/). Please note that you can always quickly run "Reformat code" (Ctrl+Alt+Enter) to fix the formatting issues.